# If I update an object, will it update it everywhere?

Tags: java

If I update an object in my code, does it update it everywhere, or will I have to refresh it?

For example:

An arraylist contains the object Cat

```
ArrayList<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
Cat Abbie = new Cat("Abbie");
cats.put(Abbie);
```

If I then change Abbie outside of this, would I have to refresh Abbie in the arraylist? For exmaple:

```
Abbie.setName("Putter");
if(cats.get(0).getName().equals(Abbie.getName()){
     //Are their names the same?
}
```

Comment: You shall test the code before posting it here.

Comment: +0 -0 Yes, learn to experiment on your own. You've already written the code :)

Comment: This is not a behavior your code should rely on.  It's very confusing for human readers of your code.

Comment: @Gilbert depends entirely on the program. For example physics object in a game instinctively makes sense to be changed everywhere it can be refered to and those changes to be seen everywhere (e.g. physics engine moves it but your code applys external forces)

Answer (score 1):

When you pass object to method you actually pass reference to this object by value. So, when you change content of object you refer to it by reference and therefore all other places that refer to the same reference will see the changes.

BTW list does not have method `put()`, it has method `add()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, references point to the object original created using `new`. So when you change the object through one reference, other references will point to the same object still, so when you access the object properties through them, of course it will return the same thing.

You can experiment and discover the answer yourself :) Functions that do deep copying will not exhibit the same behavior of course!